# How to build 2 columns with a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, multiple-columns

I had built a 2-column table td from looping through a list as follows:

```
<style>
.columns2 {
   columns: 2;
}
</style>

        <tr>
            <td class="columns2">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="accident in list">
                        <a class="openPage" ng-click="openAccidentPage('{{accident.id}}')">
                            {{accident.displayName}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Unfortunately, as the list is long (100 elements), the table flickers each time an element is inserted with the ng-repeat.

Is there a way to hold from recomputing the table at each repeat?

Comment: Use `track by` in ng-repeat. example `ng-repeat="accident in list track by accident.id"` so that entire table is not refreshed. And you just need to do `openAccidentPage(accident.id)` no need of interpolation.

Comment: It makes not differences. The issue comes from columns: 2. If I remove it, no more issue.

Comment: sorry i did not understand your question then...

Comment: Have you tried using ng-bind instead of the {{}} brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I managed to find a workaround the table flickering cause by the columns:2 and the ng-repeat.

Snippet as follows:

```
<div ng-init="list0 = list.splice(0,list.length/2)"></div>
<div ng-init="list1 = list"></div>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li
                        ng-repeat="accident in list0">
                        <a class="openPage" ng-click="openAccidentPage(accident.id)">
                            {{accident.displayName}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li
                        ng-repeat="accident in list1">
                        <a class="openPage" ng-click="openAccidentPage(accident.id)">
                            {{accident.displayName}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
```